# Problem displaying and saving the data from one recycle view to another

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I am new to Android and I can't understand why when I send data from one activity to another it doesn't remember the values that I saved previously and it's not able to show me more than one item inside the shopping cart.

Example :

I have a shopping list and a cart list

Inside the shopping list, I have a `recycleview` and I have items that I can add to the shopping cart when I press the add button, the item is added to the shopping cart by sending the data to the cart activity and it shows me the data inside the recycle view(this `recycleview` is inside the Cart activity) but now if I go back using the back button of the phone and I select another item from the shopping list when I go to the cart list the previous item added it's gone and I don't understand why since I created an `ArrayList` and I save the data inside it. Can anyone explain to me what I'm doing wrong?

I will add 3 photos to explain myself better.

[image]

[image]

In the second picture, if I go back from shopping cart to the shopping list and click on C, A from Shopping cart will disappear and I will have just C.

This is my code:

**Shopping list:**

```
public class FirebaseSearch extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText mSearchField;
private ImageButton mSearchBtn;
private ImageButton AddToCart;
private ImageButton Cart;

String searchText="";

private RecyclerView mResultList;
private DatabaseReference mUserDatabase;




private static ArrayList<Users> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
public static int cart_count = 0;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_firebasesearch);

    mUserDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");

    mSearchField = findViewById(R.id.search_field);
    mSearchBtn   = findViewById(R.id.search_btn);
    mResultList  = findViewById(R.id.result_list_cart);
    AddToCart    = findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
    Cart         = findViewById(R.id.cartButton);

    mResultList.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mResultList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    mSearchBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            searchText = mSearchField.getText().toString();
            firebaseUserSearch(searchText);
        }
    });

    Cart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        private Object Tag="Activity";

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (cart_count < 1) {

            } else {
                startActivity(new Intent(FirebaseSearch.this, CartActivity.class));
            }
        }
    });
}



private void firebaseUserSearch(String searchText) {
    Toast.makeText(FirebaseSearch.this, "Started Search", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Query firebaseSearchQuery = 
   mUserDatabase.orderByChild("Name").startAt(searchText).endAt(searchText + "\uf8ff");
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Users, UsersViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new 
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Users, UsersViewHolder>(
            Users.class,
            R.layout.list_layout,
            UsersViewHolder.class,
            firebaseSearchQuery
    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(UsersViewHolder viewHolder, Users model, int position) {
            viewHolder.getDetails(model.getName(), model.getSurname(),model.getPrice());
            viewHolder.setDetails(model.getName(), model.getSurname(),model.getPrice());
        }
    };
    mResultList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
}


@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    invalidateOptionsMenu();
}

// View Holder Class
public static class UsersViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    View mView;
    String nome;
    String surname;
    Long prezzo;
    public UsersViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mView = itemView;
        ImageButton addToCart = (ImageButton)mView.findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
        addToCart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                cart_count++;
                Context context = v.getContext();
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, CartActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("Name",nome);
                intent.putExtra("Surname",surname);
                intent.putExtra("Prezzo",Long.toString(prezzo));
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    public void getDetails(String name,String cognome,Long price){
        nome=name;
        surname=cognome;
        prezzo=price;
    }


    public void setDetails(String name, String surname, Long price) {

        TextView user_name = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.name_text);
        TextView user_surname = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.status_text);
        TextView user_price = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.price);

        user_name.setText(name);
        user_surname.setText(surname);
        user_price.setText(Long.toString(price));

    }
}
}enter code here
```

**Shopping CART :**

```
public class CartActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private RecyclerView cities;
private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
String nome,cognome;
Long prezzo;
int totalPrice=0;
TextView campoPrezzo;
int position=0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cart);

    campoPrezzo=findViewById(R.id.TotalPrice);

    //Receive the data from the previous activity
    String passedArg = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Name");
    nome=passedArg;
    String passedArg2 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Surname");
    cognome=passedArg2;

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String str = intent.getStringExtra("Prezzo");

    ArrayList<Users> cities = initCities(nome,cognome,Long. parseLong(str));


    this.cities = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.cartList);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    this.cities.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    adapter = new ProductAdapter(cities);
    this.cities.setAdapter(adapter);
    System.out.println("Prezzo"+returnTotalPrice());
}

private ArrayList<Users> initCities(String nome,String cognome,Long price) {
    ArrayList<Users> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(position,new Users(nome,cognome,price));
    position++;
    getTotalPrice(price);
    return list;
}

public void getTotalPrice(Long price){
    totalPrice+=price;
}

public int returnTotalPrice(){
    return totalPrice;
}
}
```

Comment: When you click the addToCartButton you are creating a new Instance of the CartActivity and passing it the data of only one item in the intent. You never persist this data. Here you can see the different ways you can persist your state: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/saving-states.html#options_for_preserving_ui_state

Answer (score 1):

You must save in the database which elements you clicked (sent to the shopping cart) in order for them not to load again or to be shown every time you enter the shopping cart. You are just populating the RecyclerView with all the options and you're not saving the ones you have in the ShoppingCartActivity. When you start the shopping cart activity it will load the extras from the Intent, if you didn't click any item the intent won't have extras, therefore the shopping cart won't have any items to show if you start it again. If you need help setting up the database just ask. Also you should add firebase tag to the post.

Comment: I get your point but I don't want to save them to the database (the items that I send to the Shopping cart) I just want to save the data locally because I downloaded some cart apps from git and all of them save the data using a vector. The only difference between me and them is that I send the data that I received from a database to another activity. They just create a vector with the items and send the vector[i] to the other activity and for them is working.

Comment: I don't know how they do it, but if you want to do it locally you could use SharedPreferences, which allows you to store information locally, for example you could store an id and quantity and then in the ShoppingCartActivity look for those ids in the database and just populate the recyclerView with the info you get from the database

Comment: Here's some documentation in case you need it, https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences?authuser=1

Comment: I decided to save the data to firebase and I did it, the only problem is that I have to understand how can I create a different object for every item because for now the request to write on the database is generating just 1 object and is updating this one like I just send one object not 3 or 4.

Comment: Can you add the code for me to check it? What I suggest is that you make a model, a class for every item with getters and setters, variables like "name", "price", "description", etc; once you have that done you should make a new instance of the class you created with the variables, and then upload it to firebase like `mDatabase.child("you path").push().setValue(item);` Sorry instead of using push you should put your uid

Comment: `//CartReference  <br/>
        DatabaseReference cartItems = mDatabase.child("cart-items");  <br/>

        //You should do this once you click your item  <br/>
        //Create a new instance of your custom class for each of the items clicked<br/>
        ClickedItem item = new ClickedItem(name, description, price, etc);  <br/>

        //Then upload that class to the database, note that the names you gave to the variables are going to be the  <br/>
        //names in the database<br>  <br/>
        cartItems.child(currentUser.getUid()).setValue(item);<br/>`

Comment: Don't worry I understood and it worked. Thank you so much

Comment: I'm glad you could do it, let me know if you need anymore help.